# Python Filter with a design pattern for a list

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to filter data from a list. It would be configure based. So that when changes come - I will have the option to make the changes. I have a data object as like

```
[
    {
        "student_id": A01,
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "one"
    },
    {
        "student_id": A01,
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "two"
    },
    {
        "student_id": A01,
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "three"
    },
    {
        "student_id": A01,
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "four"
    },
    ....
]
```

Now I need to filter for a school where they will require `class two and four` and rest of others will require `all data including all classes`. I have a class like :

```
// Base Class
class FilterBase(object):
    def filter_by_class(self, content):
        pass

// student filter
class StudentFilter(FilterBase):
    def __init__(self, filters=None):
        self._filters = list()
        if filters is None:
            return

    def filter_by_class(self, content):
        for filter in self._filters:
            content = filter(content)
        return content


get_class_two_four = [
      "class": "two",
      "class": "four"
]
default = [] // for default it will return full list

//filtered result 
filter_obj = StudentFilter([
            get_class_two_four
        ])
```

How do I get my expected output  like this:

```
[
    {
        "student_id": A01,
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "two"
    },
    {
        "student_id": A01,
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "four"
    },
    ....
]
```

Comment: @SteveK I did it

Comment: Might want to rename your `filter()` methods in your classes as well so they're not confused with Python's `filter()`.

Comment: You don't need the `return` in `__init__` as it already returns `None`. It's also not doing anything there as it's at the end of the function already.

Comment: @SteveK .. trying to use `__init__` to get all data if it has `default or null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following data structures:

```py
student_list = [
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "one"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "two"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "three"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "four"
    }
]

class_set = {"two", "four"}
```

You can implement a `student_in_classes` helper function that tells you whether or not the student is in one of the filtered classes. If the class filter is empty, just return all students.

```py
class FilterBase(object):
    def __init__(self, filters : set = set()):
        self._filters = filters

class StudentFilter(FilterBase):
    def __init__(self, class_set : set = set()):
        super().__init__(class_set)

    def filter_by_class(self, student_data : list):
        # No point in filtering if nothing to filter on
        return student_data if not self._filters else list(filter(self.student_in_classes, student_data))

    # When student's class matches a filter, this will return True
    def student_in_classes(self, student_dict : dict):
       # Using .get() to handle cases where class isn't provided
       return student_dict.get("class", None) in self._filters
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```py
sf_no_filter = StudentFilter()
sf_2_filters = StudentFilter(class_set)
print(sf_no_filter.filter_by_class(student_list)) # No filter provided
print(sf_2_filters.filter_by_class(student_list)) # 2 class filters
```

with the output of

```py
# No Filter Provided
[
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "one"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "two"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "three"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "four"
    }
]


# Classes "two" and "four" provided
[
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "two"
    },
    {
        "student_id": "A01",
        "student_name": "Full Name",
        "class": "four"
    }
]
```

Depending on your requirements/implementation, it might make more sense to have the constructor take in both the class filters and the student list, that way you can make/call a simple `get_filtered()` on your instance of `StudentFilter` that returns the same thing `filter_by_class()` does.

Also, for the sake of naming classes, it probably makes more sense to name it `ClassFilter` instead of `StudentFilter` since the classes are your static filtering criteria per instance.

Comment: `sf_2_filters.filter_by_class(student_list)  # 2 class filters` returns `TypeError: Object of type filter is not JSON serializable` .

Comment: `type(sf_2_filters.filter_by_class(student_list))` is a `list` - make sure you have my latest edits.